# sscanf formatting and output allowances

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am trying to understand `sscanf` formatting.  Can it take arrays of C strings to output to (the code below gives a segfault, which is what prompted the question)?  Also, when trying to take only specific characters for a string, is the format `%[abc]s` where `abc` is the set of characters to keep?

```
char s[] = "This is a 345.454 test";
char str[6][256];
double f;
sscanf(s,"%s %*s %*s %f %s",s[0],f,s[1]);
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    printf("%s\n",s[i]);
```

Comment: In the `scanf` call and the loop, are you supposed to use e.g. `str[1]` instead of `s[1]`?

Comment: You need to provide the address of the destination for scanned elements, rather than the value that they currently have. As such, `s[0]`, `f`, `s[1]` are all invalid inputs. You need to provide the address of each of these variables - `&s[0]`, `&f`, `&s[1]` - Also, it seems likely that you intend to put results into the `str` array, rather than the `s` array.

Comment: the parameters to any of the scanf() family of functions are: first the format string, followed by the addresses of the destination parameters.   The posted code is passing the contents of the destination parameters, which the sscanf() will treat as addresses and will try to write to those addresses.  That (writing to those addresses) is what is causing the seg fault event

Comment: Note: `"%[abc]s"` should be `"%[abc]"`  (no `s`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-write the `sscanf` line as follows -

```
sscanf(s,"%s %*s %*s %lf %s",str[0],&f,str[1]);
                                    ^address of float variable required
```

And in `for loop` print value of array `str`.

See working code here-https://ideone.com/hFpvDJ

Answer (score 0):

`s[0]` is a character, but you have it matched up with a `%s` format, which expects a string (the *address* of a character, the first in a sequence where the parsed value should go).

Comment: not quite true, s[0] is the address of the first row of a 2d array

Comment: @user3629249 `s[0]` is a `char`  `str[0]` may be an address of the first row of a 2d array.

Comment: @user3629249: `s` is an array of characters, hence `s[0]` is an element of that array: a character.  What makes you think it has anything to do with a 2d array; were you thinking of `str`?